# The import com.paulhammant cannot be resolved

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, gradle

The gradle Build is successful but ngwedriver is not imported

I have tried to add ngwebdriver dependency from both mavenCental and downloaded jar

```
implementation group: 'com.paulhammant', name: 'ngwebdriver', version: '1.2'
implementation files('dependency/ngwebdriver.jar')
```

The gradle build is Success and my test file import is

```
import com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.NgWebDriver;
```

The import is showing an error

```
The import com.paulhammant cannot be resolved
```

Help me with this